# Using ntpd on Ubuntu for Windows 7 client?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, ntp

I've just `aptitude install ntp` on my Ubuntu box, and now I'd like my Windows 7 desktop to synchronize its time with that machine.

The Ubuntu box is synchronising with my ISP's time servers correctly:

```
Jan  9 08:32:51 shuttle ntpd[9457]: synchronized to 81.187.81.101, stratum 2
Jan  9 08:32:51 shuttle ntpd[9457]: time reset +99.837009 s
Jan  9 08:32:51 shuttle ntpd[9457]: kernel time sync status change 0001
Jan  9 08:36:16 shuttle ntpd[9457]: synchronized to 81.187.81.101, stratum 2
```

Then I go to Control Panel / Date and Time / Internet Time and click on "Change Settings". I've entered my Ubuntu server's name in the "Internet Time Settings" dialog and clicked the "Update now" button.

Windows, in its typically loquacious fashion, reports "An error occurred while Windows was synchronizing with shuttle.home.local", and gives no further information.

How can I diagnose this problem? Does Windows 7 log this "error" anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I was being impatient. Waiting for a few minutes, and it suddenly works. Maybe ntpd doesn't respond until it's happy that it has the correct time itself?